# не могу переустановить gulp ни глобально, ни локально

Tags: gulp

Был 3 gulp, решил обновить до 4. И как то неудачно все пошло. В итоге на моей Убунте нода выше 6.x не ставится, а gulp вообще никак не ставится. Подскажите, как исправить? `
На все действия с gulp терминал выдает:

> Command 'gslp' from package 'ghostscript' (main)
>   gulp: command not found
>   paw@paw-System-Product-Name:~/Рабочий стол/lessons/webdevelop/gulp_tests/4$ gulp -v
>   No command 'gulp' found, did you mean:
>    Command 'gslp' from package 'ghostscript' (main)
>   gulp: command not found
>   paw@paw-System-Product-Name:~/Рабочий стол/lessons/webdevelop/gulp_tests/4$ sudo npm install gulpjs/gulp#4.0 --save-dev
>   [sudo] password for paw: 
>   npm ERR! code 1
>   npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git /home/paw/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d7910463
>   npm ERR! /home/paw/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d7910463/.git: Permission denied
>   npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/paw/.npm/_logs/2018-11-26T18_06_11_343Z-debug.log
paw@paw-System-Product-Name:~/Рабочий стол/lessons/webdevelop/gulp_tests/4$ gulp -v
No command 'gulp' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gslp' from package 'ghostscript' (main)
gulp: command not found
paw@paw-System-Product-Name:~/Рабочий стол/lessons/webdevelop/gulp_tests/4$

`

Как вычистить все и поставить gulp 4 нормально?